# Adding Elements inside another DOM element in MooTools

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

Can I add an object of `Elements` inside another DOM element using grab or inject or anything else?

There are two items in the object, both of type Element that are created through Javascript:

```
var firstElem = new Element("div", {text: "something"}); // <div>something</div>
var secondElem = new Element("div", {text: "else"});     // <div>else</div>
var myDivs = new Elements([firstElem, secondElem]);
```

`myDivs` contains both the elements (firstElem, secondElem) as an array and I want to add this `myDivs` object to the DOM element below, using something like `$("container").grab(myDivs)`. So the DOM state before adding looks like:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

After adding, it looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>else</div>
</div>
```

But I'm getting this error when calling `$("container").grab(myDivs)`:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

I could add each Element to the container one by one, but am wondering if there's a way to add an object of `Elements` directly due to the way my solution is architected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ought to use `.adopt()` instead. See this example on jsBin: http://jsbin.com/anayu

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){ 

  var firstElem  = new Element("div", {text: "something"}); 
  var secondElem = new Element("div", {text: "else"}); 
  var myDivs     = new Elements([firstElem, secondElem]); 

  $("container").adopt(myDivs); 

});
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what would be the advantage of using adopt() instead of appendChild() ? @Sampson

Comment: @PatrickLawler The native DOM method `appendChild` accepts only a single element reference. If you wanted to append multiple elements, you'd have to add them to a `documentFragment`, and then append the fragment. MooTools' *adopt* method allows you to pass one or more elements, including a collection.

Answer (score 4):

**[Element method: adopt](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:adopt)**

> Works like Element:grab, but allows multiple elements to be adopted.

That should be exactly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. adopt works great! dunno where i'd be without SO